# How to perform Search on a last keyed in record in a SQL column?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with 3 columns example below. The table is populated with few records. I am given a task to search through each `debtorid` below,  and return the last occurrence of a specific status lets say `PTP`. I query through the table order by the `followupdate` as below:

```
    SELECT TOP 50 [status],[FollowupDate],debtorid 
    FROM dbo.FollowUp 
    WHERE ( dbo.FollowUp.FollowUpDate >= '01-01-2014 00:00:00.000' 
          and dbo.FollowUp.FollowUpDate <= '01-10-2014 23:59:00.00')  
    ORDER BY FollowUpDate
```

[image]

From the table above, the last the [status] 'PTP' record for debtorid '589009' is at the first row and I want the first row returned, for [debtorid] 589006 is on the second row and finally for `debtorid` '589002' is third on the table from below/`DESC` order. The query should return those three rows presumably . Please how do I archive this.

I thought I should be able to return the status 'PTP' from the table by simply like

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [tblname] WHERE date BETWEEN date1 and dat2 AND status='PTP'
```

HOWEVER this is not table wise. Its rather `debtorid` wise which is a column in the table and

Comment: What would you expect TOP 1 to be based on without ORDER BY?

Comment: The TOP 1 query is just example of what i have tried. Pls do you have any suggestion on how i can achieved the above?

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick:

```
SELECT Status, DebtorId, MAX(FollowUpDate)
FROM dbo.FollowUp
WHERE Status = 'PTP'
GROUP BY
  Status, DebtorId;
```

Note that e.g. debtor 589002 has more than one status of 'PTP' on the same day, hence the need for the GROUPING to ensure that duplicates are ignored.

Comment: (Or do you have additional columns in the table which are also needed in the result, e.g. do you have a PK on the table as well, and you need to return an exact table row?)

Comment: Yah i do have many columns sir. But this is a subquery in a mega query. I am convinced your answer will do the trick like you said . I tested and seem to return what i need. To embed in the mega query , will just requre the debtorid i think. So that i can use where debtorid in (the query above). Thanks will tick your answer as soon as i finish testing, Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
SELECT    DISTINCT Status,DebtorId,FollowupDate 
FROM      dbo.FollowUp 
WHERE     Status='PTP'
AND       FollowupDate BETWEEN date1 AND date2
```